# How to watch a value bound to another controller from a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, watch

I'm trying to watch some values in an video upload box, I've got the normal inputs working but when it comes to my custom made select boxes things get a bit trickier since they don't have an `ng-model` set for them.

**EDIT:** Could this be some isolated scope issue or something similar? Seems odd though since I can see that I'm getting all the info from the controller, but the watch doesn't want to watch the values.

In my `coForms` controller I've done this to set a "value" for the select:

```
coForms.selectOption = function(option) {
  coForms.currentOption = option;
};
```

And in my directive I've done like this to watch the values:

```
video.directive('videoUpload', [function() {

    return {
        scope: {
            video: '='
        },
        controller: 'CoFormsCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'co',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/components/video/video-upload.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$watch('video.title', function(newVal, oldVal) {
                scope.video.formData.title = newVal;
            });

            scope.$watch('video.description', function(newVal, oldVal) {
                scope.video.formData.description = newVal;
            });

            scope.$watchCollection('video.tags.filteredTags', function(newVal, oldVal) {
                scope.video.formData.tags = newVal;
            });

            // How do I make this one work?
            scope.$watch('scope.co.currentOption', function(newVal, oldVal) {

            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

How can I watch the value of my custom made select box? The value resides in `scope.co.currentOption`, but I don't understand how to watch this value inside my directive once I've declared it with `controller` and `controllerAs`. Any ideas?

Comment: try `scope.$watch('co.currentOption',...`

Comment: I did but it doesn't work, I only get access to 'co' via the scope but it still doesn't want to watch the value

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
video.directive('videoUpload', [function() {    
    return {
        scope: {
            video: '='
        },
        controller: 'CoFormsCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'co',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/components/video/video-upload.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

            // How do I make this one work?
            scope.$watch(function() {
               return ctrl.currentOption;
            }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
               // ...
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Can you create a jsbin/fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
 in html `<div video-upload ctrl="coForms"></div>` and in directive should be

```
video.directive('videoUpload', [function() {

    return {
        templateUrl: 'app/views/components/video/video-upload.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

             scope.ctrl = scope.$eval(attrs.ctrl);
             scope.video = scope.$eval(attrs.video);
            // How do I make this one work?
            scope.$watch('ctrl.currentOption', function(newVal, oldVal) {
// It will work
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: I don't see how this is needed, but it doesn't work either so :|

Comment: can u try with <div video-upload ctrl="coForms"></div>

Comment: Same result unfortunately.

Comment: I have created a demo for same, please check once http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyYYjG

Answer (score 0):

if you not able to catch on scope level, assigned that to $rootScope.currentOption. 
I am not sure but there is problem if you watch model/var from other other controller and trying to access in directive.

Hope this Help!!

Comment: I don't wish to clutter the rootScope though, unless it's the last option available to me. Still haven't gotten this to work so I'll have to investigate.